# How to pick and rewrite specific parts of a text file in c#?

Tags: c#, file

I have a text file as follows:

> 22    3
>   18    10  10
>   0 0   0   0   2   3   2
>   15    9   0   0   1   20
>   17    9   0   0   1   17

I read this text file as:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
StreamReader file = new StreamReader("../../normal.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(line);
   counter++;
}
```

After that, I want to delete the first 2 rows. In addition to this, pick the first and the third character in remaining rows, and rewrite them under the text that has been read already. So that the final output would be:

> 22    3
>   18    10  10
>   0 0   0   0   2   3   2
>   15    9   0   0   1   20
>   17    9   0   0   1   17
>   0 0
>   15    0
>   17    0

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like that:

```
List<string> lineList = new List<string>();
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    lineList.add(line);
    counter++;
}

for(int i = 2; i < lineList.Count; i++) {
    string[] split = lineList[i].Split(new char[] {' '});
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", split[0], split[2]));
}
```

Comment: Take the input from the file. Delete the first two rows. The next row then would be: 0   0   0   0   2   3   2. For all remaining rows, only take the first and the third number, which would be 0 0 in this case and so on. Finally add everything to the original content of the file. Seems fine to me at least.

Comment: Ohhh, I see it now, sorry about that, read it wrong. You get the upvote

Comment: @MichaelFaisst, your recommendation works well in console view. In addition to that, if I want to rewrite this output as a text file, how can I do this?

Comment: Instead of printing the newly generated line out to console, you could add it to a new list of strings. After the for loop, you could use the File.AppendAllLines Function to append all the new lines to the existing file.

Answer (score 0):

To get the *specified* output;

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines("../../normal.txt").ToList();

foreach (string item in lines.Skip(2))
{
    data = item.Split(new char[] {' '}).ToList();
    lines.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", data[0], data[2]);
}
```

Comment: is there any benefit in converting your split array to a list?

Comment: I personally prefer list over array since it's expendable.

Comment: okay but in this specific example there is no benefit to it...was just wondering^^

Answer (score 0):

```
     var existingLines = File.ReadAllLines("../../normal.txt");
     var newLines = new List<string>();
     var appendedLines = new List<string>();

     for (var i = 2; i < existingLines.Length; i++)
     {
            // add a line
            newLines.Add(existingLines[i]);

            // add first and third character to the line
            var split = existingLines[i].Split(' ');
            appendedLines.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", split[0], split[2]));
     }
     newLines.AddRange(appendedLines);

     File.WriteAllLines("../../newText.txt", newLines);
```